# Filtering date string formatted as mm-yyyy LINQ query by date?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, linq, datetime

We have Date as a string in mm-yyyy. In Db the date field is stored as varchar. We need to filter the date by linq.

```
.where(m=>m.ItemId == itemId && DbFunctions.CreateDateTime
(m.INV_GRN.ExpDate.Split('-')[1].CompareTo(2019), m.INV_GRN.ExpDate.Split('-')
[1].CompareTo(2), 1, 0, 0, 0.0) >= DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(2019,2,1,0,0,0.0))
```

We need to compare by spliting the date by comparing splitting the date into month and year part. How can we do Extract the month and year part so as to compare?

So what's the best way to go, and what am I missing?

Comment: Is it that you want to get every item that has a matching ID and the date is greater than or equal to (in this example) 01-Feb-2019?  I am confused by your use of the `CompareTo` function's result being passed into a date creation function. The value of [CompareTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compareto?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_CompareTo_System_String_) is not going to give you back the year part or the mathematical difference of the year, it just shows you whether your string precedes or follows the comparing string based on sort order.

Comment: You can grab the month from `DateTime.Month` and year from `DateTime.Year`, if you only want to compare the two.

Answer (score 0):

If you collection already is just mm-yyyy we can simply call `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending`

Otherwise, we can do something like this

```
{
   var dateTimeStrings = database.GetAllDateTimes(); /* get our strings in dd-mm-yyyy format */

    var dateTimes = dateTimeStrings.Select(c => DateTime.Parse(c));
    var monthsAndYearsOnly = dateTimes.Select(dateTime => new DateTime(dateTime.year, datetime.month, 0 /* it requires days, lets pass in 0 */));

    // Lastly to get our dates ordered 
    var orderedDates = monthsAndYear.OrderBy(dateTime => dateTime); // looks strange but we're saying order by the date

    return orderedDates;
}
```

Comment: Based on the OP mentioning `filtering` and their use of `Where` in their code sample, I would suspect ordering the results is not the main issue. If you take your suggestion, tweak it a little, and provide a code sample with this as part of the `Where` clause, I think you would probably have the answer the OP is looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll get to it

Comment: Here in my case, I won't be able to use Parse, If we use parse the following exception is been thrown.  
Message=LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ParseExact(System.String, System.String, System.IFormatProvider)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
  Source=EntityFramework

Answer (score 0):

You could parse `ExpDate` to date and compaire it to a specific Date, and since both of them start with the same day you will be only compairing the month and year.

```
.Where(m=> m.ItemId == itemId && DateTime.Parse("01-"+ m.INV_GRN.ExpDate).Date >= DateTime.Parse("2019-02-01").Date)
```

Comment: Here in my case, I won't be able to use Parse, If we use parse the following exception is been thrown. Message=LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ParseExact(System.String, System.String, System.IFormatProvider)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. Source=EntityFramework

Comment: Here the date is stored as varchar in DB.